# Android using Multiple Progress Dialogs

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am trying to build a class to go to the web, download data and then load it into a database.  I have no problem doing this with a single progress dialog but can simply not figure out how to have multiple dialogs.  In researching this, I found hundreds of Progress Dialog questions, so it does not seem as straight forward as it should be.

I have tried using handlers and threads but simply cannot ma

I am looking for an example of working code to accomplish this.

Here is the pseudo code that I am attempting:

```
public class myactivity extends Activity()
{
    private WebIO webIO   ;     // web acess io
    private DataIO DataIO ;     // database  io

    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        DataIO = new DataIO( this );
        WebIO  = new WebIO();
        DataIO.open();
        runProgram();
    }
}

private void runProgram() {
    startProgressDialog( "Downloading data from web" );

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                String vData = webIO.getData();

                dismissProgressDialog();

                if  ( vData.length() > 0 ) {
                    promptUser( vData );
    } } } }
}

private void promptUser( vData ){
    if alertdialog_to_prompt_user_to_load(){
    {
        loadData( pData )
    }

private void loadData( String pData ){
    startProgressDialog( "Loading data into database" );

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                loadDataIntoDatabase();

                dismissProgressDialog();
    } } } }
}
```

Comment: Asynctask. 1 for each progress.

Comment: I tried this and still couldn't make the 2nd progressdialog work.  Is there an example using multiple progressdialogs somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way to have multiple dialogs is to layer them on top of each other, which is an obvious user experience no-no. in android, dialogs are their own window, so there can only be one in focus at a time.

to solve your problem, create a custom dialog with multiple [`ProgressBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) widgets. the simplest way to do that is to start with a [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and override `onCreatedDialog()` to return an [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) with a custom view. to set a custom view on an alert dialog, see the [`setView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) method on `AlertDialog`. e.g.,

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View layout = = li.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog);

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(..)
            .setTitle(...)
            .setView(layout)
            ...
            .create();
}
```

it'd be pretty neat to encapsulate all this into a multi-download progress dialog, where you could register additional downloads and have the class automatically add a progress bar and register itself for progress updates.

Comment: Jeffrey,  This doesn't help me at all.  I am already using a custom dialog with a custom view.  The problem is the force-close when calling it, or another one, a second time from either the "run" block or from a "runhandler".

Comment: your question doesn't say anything about a force-close, and your question asks multiple times about how to use multiple dialogs. i would suggest you post another question that more clearly addresses the problem you are having then.